# Html5/mp4 does not play in Firefox

Tags: firefox, video, mp4, html5

From my point of view it seems to be an issue with my System which is Mageia 7.1. But I don't know how to reproduce it.

Regarding to [this site](https://tekeye.uk/html/html5-video-test-page), the points **1 (HTML5 MPEG Video Test)** and **4 (HTML5 Video Test with Preload of None)** fail to play. Youtube works perfect by the way. My browser version is FF 56.02(64) (I need that version) and until now everything worked fine for years.

In firefox about:plugins **OpenH264-Videocodec by Cisco Systems, Inc.** shows as activated. Strangely there are no entries below (description, mime-type, file suffixes).
In about:config all **media.*** settings seem to be right (set to true / enabled) and I changed nothing there.

On system side VLC plays everything. So does google-chrome.

The packages I think that must be installed are:
**ffmpeg

vorbis tools

gstreamer1.0-faad

gstreamer1.0-wavpack

gstreamer1.0-libav

lib64ogg0**

It is possible that I messed somthing up when installing the dolphin extension [audioconverter](https://store.kde.org/p/998467) which wanted the packages **mplayer, ffmpeg, lame, oggenc, oggdec, flac, faac, faad, mppdec, wvunpack id3lib, vorbis-tools, metaflac, apetag and id3v2**. But this is just one possible guess.

As FF has no log or similar, strace says nothing at all when starting a non working video site.
So how would you proceed to find the problem? It occured suddenly.

thanks in advance

Comment: *My browser version is FF 56.02(64) (I need that version)* Err... No, you don't, nobody does, they just *think* they do (for whatever uninformed "reason"). **For your own (and others) online safety** please always use **supported web browser versions** and that means either the current version or the latest ESR version (Extended Support Release).

Comment: Thanks for the instruction ;)